# HCURSOR from another window, possible?

Tags: c++, windows, cursor, dwm

I'm looking for draw HCURSOR in my window. The cursor has to be the real cursor from another window (HWND).

Here is my code:

```
GetCursorPos(&pos);
ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pos);
DrawIcon(hdcMemDC, pos.x, pos.y,GetCursor());
```

It draw a cursor on my window, but it's not the "real" Windows cursor. Example, when on another window i got a hand mouse icon, mine doesn't change.

So i would like to know if it's possible to handle the "real" cursor from a specified window (HWND) and draw it. Something like `GetCursorOf(hwnd, &myCursorInfo)` would be cool.

Comment: So while the cursor is elsewhere, you have to have your own cursor in your window? By the way, the documentation for `GetCursor`: *Retrieves a handle to the current cursor.
To get information on the global cursor, even if it is not owned by the current thread, use GetCursorInfo.*

Comment: My application's goal is rendering a window into another window. I have to draw the cursor of the original window into the "copy" window. But if i do 
`GetCursorInfo(&a);/.../
DrawIcon(hdcMemDC, pos.x, pos.y,a.hCursor);` 
the cursor isn't draw anymore.

Comment: I have a feeling you're not setting `cbSize` before calling `GetCursorInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will get the cursor of any window. It will then create a thread and that thread will constantly draw the cursor onto our window.

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI BltThreadProc(void *lpParam)
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (!IsIconic((HWND)lpParam)) //if our window isn't minimised, then we get the cursor and draw it.. Makes no sense drawing on a minimised window.
        {
            CURSORINFO Info = {0};
            Info.cbSize = sizeof(Info);
            GetCursorInfo(&Info);

            HDC hDC = GetDC((HWND)lpParam);
            DrawIconEx(hDC, 0, 0, Info.hCursor, 0, 0, 0, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(COLOR_BACKGROUND), DI_NORMAL | DI_COMPAT | DI_DEFAULTSIZE);
            ReleaseDC((HWND)lpParam, hDC);
        }

        Sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, BltThreadProc, hwnd, 0, 0);
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = _T("CLS");
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(COLOR_BACKGROUND);

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, _T("CLS"), _T("Title"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 544, 375, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hThisInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return messages.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Just use `DrawIcon` with `Info.hCursor`. It's so much simpler, and it works: http://i.imgur.com/K7Zt3Tc.png

Comment: I validate your answer as the solution of this topic cause it contains the right answer.